# Stored procedure has too many arguments specified C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored  procedure like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE p_UpdateCampaignGadget 
    @campaignID NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @accountNumber NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @Phone01 NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @CallResult NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CallStatusZone1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CallStatusZone2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @CallbackDateTime01 NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @FIRSTNAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @campaignEndDateTime NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

and code like:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ccap_ccConnectionString %>" 
      SelectCommand="p_ShowCampaignContacts" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
      UpdateCommand="p_UpdateCampaignGadget" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="LAB_OUTBOUND_C1_C" Name="campaignID" QueryStringField="ID" Type="String" />
      </SelectParameters>
      <UpdateParameters>
          <asp:Parameter Name="campaignID" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="accountNumber" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="Phone01" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="CallResult" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="CallStatusZone1" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="CallStatusZone2" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="CallbackDateTime01" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="FIRSTNAME" Type="String" />
          <asp:Parameter Name="campaignEndDateTime" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I use this procedure on gridview update.

Why do I get this error

> Stored procedure has too many arguments specified

Comment: Check for existence of `dbo.<your proc name>` and `<your login>.<your proc name>`. After that prefix sp name with actual schema name in your C# code. And check connection params (db and server) you're actually connecting with.

Comment: **Side note:** you should **NOT** just define every parameter as `nvarchar(max)` because you're too lazy to think about what the **appropriate** data type would be!  If your parameter is called `campaignEndDateTime` - my guess is it **should be**  a `DATETIME` - ***NOT*** a stirng!

Comment: Is 'campaignID' a primary key and auto-incremented column?

Comment: This error mostly occur when gridview DataKeyNames="id" not pass to sp as parameter , but logically this parameter also pass to sp , if this parameter already pass then check whether Bind key also pass as parameter to sp